# Jenkins : Is it possible to give user access for selected parameters in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job which is used for deployment to multiple systems. The job has multiple parameters.
Parameter 1 : Text box : release number input
Parameter 2 : Radio buttons: Destination systems [SYS_1,SYS_2,SYS_3]

If I am creating as user (user_1). Is is possible to allow the user to select only SYS_1 or SYS_2 from the radio button while running the job ?. Similarly user_2 will should have access to select only SYS_1 & SYS_3.

Any other suggestions for access control for multiple system deployment are also welcome!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [active-choices-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) Jenkins plugin.

But I prefer to use Jenkins pipelines with an [`input` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)